# How can i make apache to include all files from folder

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I know i can do this

```
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/php.conf"
```

How can i make apache to load all files in some dir like

```
Include /usr/mydir/*
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do:

```
Include dir/*
```

For example in `Debian` the modules are included this way, from `apache2.conf`:

```
# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: BTW, this is not platform specific. The syntax is exactly the same on Windows (including using forward slash for the path).